# Use custom subscriber key with Exact Target Web Collect

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm using ExactTarget's web collect functionality to collect new sign ups from our website. I want to use a custom subscriber key when a new subscriber account is created in ET using web collect but it seems like web collect uses the customer email address as the subscriber key. Is there a way I can pass subscriber key in the query sting. I have tried it but it doesn't seem to work.

See code here. harded coded "990-1tes@test.com" for testing purposes.

```
   <form action="http://cl.s4.exct.net/subscribe.aspx" name="subscribeForm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="thx" name="thx" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="err" value="YOUR ERROR PAGE HERE" />
<input type="hidden" name="usub" value="YOUR SUCCESS UNSUB PAGE HERE" />
<input type="hidden" name="MID" value="1069927" />
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" name="Subscriber Key" VALUE="990-1test@test.com" />
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" name="Email Address" VALUE="2hahid@ticketmastertt.co.uk" />
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" name="CLIENT_CODE" VALUE="9999" />
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" name="lid" VALUE="32347" />
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">

    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="Email Type" value="HTML" checked="checked" />
        <font face="Verdana" size="2">HTML</font>
    </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="Email Type" value="TEXT" />
            <font face="Verdana" size="2"> Text</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="SubAction" value="add" checked="checked" />
            <font face="Verdana" size="2">Subscribe</font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="SubAction" value="unsub" />
            <font face="Verdana" size="2">Unsubscribe</font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            <td align="right">
            <font face="verdana" size="1" color="#4C5487">
            Powered by<br> <a href="http://www.exacttarget.com">
            <img src="http://www.exacttarget.com/gfx/smalllogo.gif" border="0"></a>
            </font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "ETSubscriberKey" instead of "Subscriber Key"

Comment: You have it working then?

Comment: Yes, all working now