# Pass subscriber key to Exact Target web collect

Tags: marketing-cloud, web

I'm trying to pass in a Subscriber Key to Exact target using a web collect form. I've tried the solution here [Use custom subscriber key with Exact Target Web Collect](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/36291/use-custom-subscriber-key-with-exact-target-web-collect/36305?newreg=02b555cf623d4922963db57d2ffc39e6) which suggests to use ETSubscriberKey but this stops the web collect form from working (although no errors are received).

So basically I have an email field goose@gander.com which is fine and I'm trying to append my company name to the subscriber key Mysite_goose@gander.com.

The field currently looks like this:

```
<input class="ETSubscriberKey" type="text" id="ETSubscriberKey" maxlength="80" name="ETSubscriberKey" size="20" >
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
C

Answer (score 0):

@SxChoc use like this

```
<input class="ETSubscriberKey" type="text" id="Subscriber Key" maxlength="80" name="Subscriber Key" size="20" >
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that sadly that doesn't pass the information into ET